# What is the proper way to add an 'App Link Button' inside an Android Apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-links

I know how to implement an [App Link Button](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app) inside an App.

A few days ago, i got a mail from Google Play that i can't use a button which will redirect user to my Google Play app.

[image]

I added that button on the bottom of the main screen. Perhaps i'm not clear about what they says on the mail.

[image]

So i want to know how to add that button. When user will touch that button then they will go to that app details inside "Play Store" app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I know how to implement an App Link Button inside an App" does not match up with "So i want to know how to add that button". If your question really is "why did Google Play send me the nasty email?", [we cannot really help with that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @CommonsWare i want to know that where and how will i add that button so that i will not create any Google play violation?

Comment: As I noted, [we cannot really help with that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app store Policy are off topic for Stack Overflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic